# Oracle and DB2 users are OS users?

Tags: oracle, db2

I am trying to decrypt some database script outputs, and I need to know if the Oracle and the DB2 users are also OS users (on Linux) or they are only internal users of the database. In other words, when I create a database user, is an OS user also created?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Oracle at least, no, creating a database user does not create an operating system user. You can have an [externally-authenticated](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/network.1111/e16543/authentication.htm#CHDBIHHA) database user (traditionally defined with a common prefix like `ops$`, e.g. `ops$osuser`, [though that isn't necessary](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/initparams176.htm#REFRN10152)), but the matching OS user still has to be created separately. So you can have a user that exists in both the OS and database, but the OS user is not created by the database `create user` command.

Aside from that situation, why would it be a useful or sensible thing to do? It would also mean the Oracle account had to have permission to do so, i.e root or administrator privs, which would be a potentially dangerous privilege escalation hole; and would have to coordinate so that, for example, you couldn't create a database user with an ID matching an existing OS user.

I can't imagine DB2 would create an OS user either, but I don't know for sure; I have no experience of that so someone else will need to answer that part...

Comment: In DB2 a database user must match an OS user (at least that's how it works on the Express-C version that I have)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I don't pretend to know anything about DB2 *8-) Does it create the OS user though, or does it have to already exist?

Comment: I just played around with it, and that was a while ago, but I think I had to create the OS user manually.

Answer (score 0):

DB2 security relies on external authentication and DB2 authorization. It means that the username and password are verified with an external mechanism. By default, this is the OS, but you can configure a Kerberos, or other kind of authentication.

In the DB2 examples that are included in the installation, you can create your own security plugin, to authenticate a user with an internal database mechanism.